# Problem with LINQ Group By multiple tables which have many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following two tables:
- ProductElements (which contains FK of Product and Element)
- ElementProcesses (which contains FK of Element and Process)

The relationship is many to many: so 1 product is related with multiple elements and by the other hand 1 element has multiple processes.

The data I want to get is like the following table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkvlq.jpg

I have tried the following code, which by now only displays me the first relationship.

```
var result = from item1 in db.ProductElements.GetAll(includeProperties: "Element,Product")
                   join item2 in db.ElementProcesses.GetAll(includeProperties: "Element,Process") on item1.ElementId equals item2.ElementId
                   group new { item2.Element } by new { item1.Product } into g
                   select new
                   {
                     Product = g.Key.Product.Name,
                     Elements = g.Select(t=>t.Element).Distinct(),
                   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For relationships you describe, you may have simple classes:

```
class Products
{
    public string ProdName { get; set; }
}
class Elements
{
    public string ElemName { get; set; }
}
class Processes
{
    public string ProcName { get; set; }
}
class ProductElements
{
    public Products Product { get; set; }
    public Elements Element { get; set; }
}
class ElementProcesses
{
    public Elements Element { get; set; }
    public Processes Process { get; set; }
}

        var p01 = new Products() { ProdName = "P01" };
        var p02 = new Products() { ProdName = "P02" };
        var e01 = new Elements() { ElemName = "E01" };
        var e05 = new Elements() { ElemName = "E05" };
        var e06 = new Elements() { ElemName = "E06" };
        var e08 = new Elements() { ElemName = "E08" };
        var pc01 = new Processes() { ProcName = "PC01" };
        var pc02 = new Processes() { ProcName = "PC02" };
        var pc07 = new Processes() { ProcName = "PC07" };
        var pc08 = new Processes() { ProcName = "PC08" };
        var pc09 = new Processes() { ProcName = "PC09" };
        var productElements01 = new List<ProductElements>() {
            new ProductElements(){ Product = p01, Element = e01},
            new ProductElements(){ Product = p01, Element = e06},
            new ProductElements(){ Product = p02, Element = e05},
            new ProductElements(){ Product = p02, Element = e08}};

        var elemProc01 = new List<ElementProcesses>()   {
            new ElementProcesses(){Element = e01, Process = pc01},
            {new ElementProcesses(){Element = e01, Process = pc02}},
            {new ElementProcesses(){Element = e06, Process = pc08}},
            {new ElementProcesses(){Element = e05, Process = pc07}},
            {new ElementProcesses(){Element = e08, Process = pc09}}};
```

then your query may look like this:

```
            var query = (from ps in productElements01
                           from ep in elemProc01
                         where ps.Element == ep.Element
                         select new {ps.Product, ps.Element, ep.Process});
```